# Corrupted Workbook when written with openpyxl in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I wrote below code to write to a workbook using pandas. Idea is to add a new sheet to the workbook if one with same name already exists, otherwise create a new workbook.

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from openpyxl import load_workbook

xls = pd.ExcelFile("test.xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel(xls, "Sheet1")

op_name = "op.xlsx"
my_file = Path(op_name)
if my_file.exists():
    book = load_workbook(my_file)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(op_name, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
    writer.book = book
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="r2")
else:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(op_name, engine='openpyxl')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="r1")
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

However I get the following error while opening the output workbook:

> **We found a problem with some content in 'op.xlsx'. Do you want us to try and recover as much as we can?**

I have tried multiple variations of this code but nothing has made it work.
Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: without a reproducible example it's going to be hard to help you

Comment: @Roim The error can be reproduced by running the code shared in my post

Comment: with any excel file? or is it depend on test.xlsx?

Comment: You can use any excel file. My test file has two rows and two columns, rest all is blank

Comment: It works without `writer.save()`.

Comment: @RogMatthews your code works perfectly on my computer (with a dummy "test.xlsx"). Can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your suggestion, Without ```writer.save()``` it worked in case when there wasn't an existing file, I still get the error while appending sheet to the workbook

Comment: Works for me in both cases

Comment: @Roim I am not sure what is the environment difference between our computers. Even I am unable to understand why I should get this issue in first place.

Comment: @Michael I am using Machine Learning Studio with pandas version 1.2.0 and openpyxl version 2.6.4 and it is not working for me in this environment.

Comment: @Michael Can you suggest a different way of achieving the functionality described?

Comment: @Roim Can you suggest a different way of achieving the functionality described?

Comment: Try the engine `xlsxwriter`

Comment: @Michael Unfortunately append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter...

Comment: Downvoting because not reproducible. Provide the xlsx you are having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

Hi What is the pandas version that you have used if pandas version is >= 1.2 this error occurred as mentioned in this bug report in [GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39576). Lower your pandas version to 1.1.5 or if you are particularly using this newer version please edit the library python file as below.

in pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py add these following lines

```
self.handles.handle.seek(0)
self.handles.handle.truncate()
```

below this line

```
self.book = load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
```

**This fix is for pandas >= 1.2 libraries only.**

Answer (score 0):

`op_name` is only the file name. `my_file` variable had the file path. `ExcelWriter()` takes file path parameter and not file name.

Try `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(my_file, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')`